# How to draw a graph with a row of incomplete semi-circles with a few extra edges in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs, foreach, circles

I want to draw something like the hand-drawn picture I have attached (the second picture). This is actually a portion of the line digraph of Figure 2 (with a specified orientation), which I have also attached.
I realise that I need to use a few for-each loops, but I am not sure how to draw directed edges in a for-each loop.
I apologise that I am not attaching any code, but I am quite stumped as to how to even begin.

Thank you in advance.

[image: Semi circles in a row]

[image: Line graph of semi circles in a row]

Comment: It is always a good idea to link to [related questions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/685196/47927) and/or provide some code to start with.

Comment: How is this figure defined? Is there a specific angle necessary? Is there a reason for the asymmetry? Is there a definition of it? What does make up your diagram?

Comment: Thanks, @JasperHabicht. So sorry for not doing that. I will do so in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of `\pic`s and then easily place and connect them.

Extending MS-SPO's nice answer:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\tikzset{
    pics/incomplete semicircle/.style={
        code={
            \tikzset{
                incomplete semicircle/.cd, 
                #1,
                arrow decoration outer/.style={
                    decoration={
                        markings,
                        mark={at position 0.08 with {\arrow{stealth}}},
                        mark={at position 0.20 with {\arrow{stealth}}},
                        mark={at position 0.32 with {\arrow{stealth}}},
                        mark={at position 0.44 with {\arrow{stealth}}},
                        mark={at position 0.57 with {\arrow{stealth}}},
                        mark={at position 0.76 with {\arrow{stealth}}},
                        mark={at position 0.95 with {\arrow{stealth}}}
                    },
                    postaction={decorate}
                },
                arrow decoration inner/.style={
                    decoration={
                        markings,
                        mark={at position 0.3 with {\arrow{stealth}}},
                        mark={at position 0.8 with {\arrow{stealth}}}
                    },
                    postaction={decorate}
                }
            }
            \coordinate (-A) at (150:1);
            \coordinate (-B) at (120:1);
            \coordinate (-C) at (90:1);
            \coordinate (-D) at (60:1);
            \coordinate (-E) at (30:1);
            \coordinate (-F) at (0:.5);
            \coordinate (-G) at (90:.5);
            \coordinate (-H) at (0:-.5);
            \draw[incomplete semicircle/arrow decoration outer] 
                (-A) arc[start angle=150, end angle=30, radius=1] --
                (-F) -- (-H) -- cycle;
            \draw[incomplete semicircle/arrow decoration inner] 
                (-H) -- (-G) -- (-F);
            \foreach \p in {A,B,...,H}{
                \node[circle, draw, fill=white, inner sep=0.75pt] 
                    (-n\p) at (-\p) {};
            }
        }
    },
    arrowed/.style={
        decoration={
            markings,
            mark={at position 0.55 with {\arrow{stealth}}}
        },
        postaction={decorate}
    }
}

\begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pic (c1) at (0,0) {incomplete semicircle};
    \pic (c2) at (2,0) {incomplete semicircle};
    \draw[arrowed] (c1-nF) -- (c2-nH);
    \draw[arrowed] (c2-nA) -- (c1-nF);
 \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, thank you so much @Jasper Habicht! I am super grateful for you taking the time to assist me.

Comment: @Emily You should be able to add options to style the line width (and other things) as options to the `\pic` command, such as: `\pic[line width=0.2pt] (c1) at (0,0) {incomplete semicircle};`. However, 2pt will be too thick for the above picture, I think.

Comment: Thank you, Jasper. I deleted my comment as I then was able to solve my question. For the sake of helping others, what I wanted to do is reduce the thickness of the lines for the nodes (circles) and edges (lines). What worked for me is replacing the line \draw[incomplete semicircle/arrow decoration outer] with \draw[incomplete semicircle/arrow decoration inner, *thin*] (so adding the argument "thin") as well as adding "thin" here too:  \foreach \p in {A,B,...,H}{
    \node[circle, draw, *thin*, fill=white, inner sep=1.2pt] 
    (-n\p) at (-\p) {};
Thank you so much, though for your response!

Answer (score 2):

Here is something to start with. Major steps:

- neglecting the `postaction`, drawing the "semicircle" and the filled circles is easy enough
- using `polar coorinates` makes it easy, remembering the 3 `coordinate`s A, B and C
- the `arc` takes 3 parameters after moving to its start position: (startAngle:endAngle:radius)
- decoration is finally added using the `decorations.markings` lib
- do some fine tuning on positioning them

Certainly, some code parts can further be refactored into some `foreach` loops.

Unfortunately I didn't succeed to move the whole drawing into a `\pic`. Once that works, it's easy to:

- placing 5 of them in a row
- accessing coordinates from inside the `\pic` or specifying them explicitely
- drawing the missing few connectors

[image: result]

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}
    [decoration={
        markings,
        mark=between positions 0.06 and 1 step 5.3mm with {\arrow{stealth}} 
    }]
    % ~~~ "semicircle" ~~~~~~~~~~
    \draw [postaction={decorate}] (150:1) arc(150:30:1) -- (0:.5) coordinate (B) -- (0:-.5)  coordinate (A) -- (150:1) (A) -- (90:.5) coordinate (C) -- (B) ;
    
    % ~~~ filled circles ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \draw [fill=white] (150:1) circle [radius=1pt];
    \draw [fill=white] (120:1) circle [radius=1pt];
    \draw [fill=white] (90:1) circle [radius=1pt];
    \draw [fill=white] (60:1) circle [radius=1pt];
    \draw [fill=white] (30:1) circle [radius=1pt];
    
    \draw [fill=white] (A) circle [radius=1pt];
    \draw [fill=white] (B) circle [radius=1pt];
    \draw [fill=white] (C) circle [radius=1pt];
 \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Finally, here's the code refactoring the placement of filled circles:

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}
    [decoration={
        markings,
        mark=between positions 0.06 and 1 step 5.3mm with {\arrow{stealth}} 
    }]
    % ~~~ "semicircle" ~~~~~~~~~~
    \draw [postaction={decorate}] (150:1) arc(150:30:1) -- (0:.5) coordinate (B) -- (0:-.5)  coordinate (A) -- (150:1) (A) -- (90:.5) coordinate (C) -- (B) ;
    
    % ~~~ filled circles ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    %     refactored
    \foreach \p in {(150:1),(120:1),(90:1),(60:1),(30:1),(A),(B),(C)}{
        \draw [fill=white] \p circle [radius=1pt];
    }
 \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

As Jasper commented, the path for the semicircles should be split at least here:

```
... coordinate (A) -- (150:1) (A) -- (90:.5) coordinate (C) ...
```

where I continued with the last 3 points for pure lazyness. Defining a second decoration style to better place the arrows there may be an option, too. It also may be a good choice to start the "semicircle" one point earlier, i.e. before the arc, i.e. at the lower left corner. Might have some beneficial consequences.

---

Turns out, you can split the decoration style, too; the lower left point is critical, as two pathes run through it:

[image: result2]

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}
    [decoration={
        markings,
        mark=between positions 0.06 and .5 step 5.3mm with {\arrow{stealth}} ,
        mark=between positions 0.6 and .8 step 6mm with {\arrow{stealth}} ,% new
        mark=between positions 0.835 and 1 step 6mm with {\arrow{stealth}}% new
    }]
    % ~~~ "semicircle" ~~~~~~~~~~
    \draw [postaction={decorate}] (150:1) arc(150:30:1) -- (0:.5) coordinate (B) -- (0:-.5)  coordinate (A) -- (150:1) (A) -- (90:.5) coordinate (C) -- (B) ;
    
    % ~~~ filled circles ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    %     refactored
    \foreach \p in {(150:1),(120:1),(90:1),(60:1),(30:1),(A),(B),(C)}{
        \draw [fill=white] \p circle [radius=1pt];
    }
 \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Looks like there is an arrow tip exactly behind the circle at the center. Maybe splitting the path or use different decorations could solve this.

Comment: Yes, it's there. Splitting the path as you suggest will work fine, but also tuning starting point and separation of decoration gives some choice.

Comment: @JasperHabicht, turned out, you can split the decoration style as well, see above after the horizontal rule.

Comment: Thank you so much @MS-SPO! You have helped me immensely! I am so appreciative.

Comment: Fine :) You are free to like and accept this answer, later, unless you have/n't already.