# Rectangular grid tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

There are good entries on this site on how to produce a grid with tikz. In particular, this answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12858/92346. The key seems to be the following command:

```
\draw[step=0.5cm,color=gray] (-1,-1) grid (1,1);
```

I wonder if there is a similar automation to produce grids of the following form.
[image]

Comment: Maybe `\draw[color=gray] (0,0) grid[xstep=.5cm, ystep=4cm] (10,4);`?

Comment: @Rmano I used your solution and it worked. Perhaps you can write an answer describing the parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An idea to create this is to use 3 grids with different `xstep` and `ystep`. Then, to automate the process, I can use a `pic`. More on `pic` on [this answer of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/684611/tikz-how-to-fill-a-part-of-shape-with-a-color/684652#684652)

You can toy around with the pic, create arguments to change it or use `pic actions` to transfer arguments to subparts of the pic code.

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}
    
\begin{tikzpicture}[
        threegrids/.pic ={
            \draw[ystep=5cm,xstep=1cm,color=gray] (0,0) grid (5,5);
            \draw[ystep=5cm,xstep=5cm,color=gray] (5,0) grid (10,5);
            \draw[ystep=5cm,xstep=1cm,color=gray] (10,0) grid (15,5);
            \node at(7.5,2.5) {...};    
        }
    ]
    \draw[ystep=5cm,xstep=1cm,color=gray] (0,0) grid (5,5);
    \draw[ystep=5cm,xstep=5cm,color=gray] (5,0) grid (10,5);
    \draw[ystep=5cm,xstep=1cm,color=gray] (10,0) grid (15,5);
    
    % add the dots
    \node at(7.5,2.5) {...};
    
    % using a pic
    \pic at (0,-6) {threegrids};
    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]